# Am I using any outdated logic in my php login script?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

So here is the deal, I have been following tutorials all day trying to resolve this issue I am having.

So far my webpage shows "Username invalid" , but I have confirmed in the inspector in chrome that it is infact passing the correct username and password to my login script  (below) am I doing anything wrong?!

```
<?php
    session_start();
    // Change this to your connection info.
    $DATABASE_HOST = 'db_ip';
    $DATABASE_USER = 'db_user';
    $DATABASE_PASS = 'db_pass';
    $DATABASE_NAME = 'db_name';
    // Try and connect using the info above.
    $con = mysqli_connect($DATABASE_HOST, $DATABASE_USER, $DATABASE_PASS, $DATABASE_NAME);
    if ( mysqli_connect_errno() ) {
        // If there is an error with the connection, stop the script and display the error.
        exit('Failed to connect to MySQL: ' . mysqli_connect_error());
    }
    // Now we check if the data from the login form was submitted, isset() will check if the data exists.
    if ( !isset($_POST['username'], $_POST['password']) ) {
        // Could not get the data that should have been sent.
        exit('Please fill both the username and password fields!');
    }
    // Prepare our SQL, preparing the SQL statement will prevent SQL injection.
    if ($stmt = $con->prepare("SELECT id, password FROM `accounts` WHERE username = '$username'")) {
        // Bind parameters (s = string, i = int, b = blob, etc), in our case the username is a string so we use "s"
        $stmt->execute();
        // Store the result so we can check if the account exists in the database.
        $stmt->store_result();
    if ($stmt->num_rows > 0) {
        $stmt->bind_result($id, $password);
        $stmt->fetch();
        // Account exists, now we verify the password.
        // Note: remember to use password_hash in your registration file to store the hashed passwords.
        if ($_POST['password'] === $password) {
                // Verification success! User has loggedin!
                // Create sessions so we know the user is logged in, they basically act like cookies but remember the data on the server.
                session_regenerate_id();
                $_SESSION['loggedin'] = TRUE;
                $_SESSION['name'] = $_POST['username'];
                $_SESSION['id'] = $id;
                echo 'Welcome ' . $_SESSION['name'] . '!';
        } else {
                echo 'Incorrect password!';
        }
    } else {
        echo 'Incorrect username!';
    }
        $stmt->close();

    }
?>
```

Comment: While your code looks correct to me, I would caution you against storing plain-text passwords in a database.  It's common practice to take a hash of the password and compare this to an already hashed version in the database.  They should match.  Additionally, if the password is salted before being hashed.  Both the salt and hash are stored in the database.  Then the data would be salted, then hashed, then compared to what was stored in the database.

Comment: Another thing to pay attention to is that this code is vulnerable to SQL injection.  What if I typed the following as my username: `(DELETE FROM accounts)`?  This would become a subquery in your SQL statement, and I could potentially do a lot of damage to your database.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve my issue with the following:

where I was defining $stmt I was using $username when it had not been defined yet, I changed this line

```
$con->prepare("SELECT id, password FROM `accounts` WHERE username = '$username'"))
```

to

```
$con->prepare('SELECT id, password FROM `accounts` WHERE username = ?'))
```

and added this above my execute statement:

```
$stmt->bind_result($id, $password);
```

Comment: Don't save the passwords in your database directly only hashed values

Comment: Great that you changed it, but for the future always remember *never include other strings in your SQL statements*, this is an SQL injection vulnerability!